# React Quill - formatText function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, quill, react-quill

```js
  changeHeader = (h = false) => {
    this.editor.focus();
    let selection = this.editor.getSelection();
    let value;
    switch (h) {
    case "Heading 01":
      value = 1;
      break;
    case "Heading 02":
      value = 2;
      break;
    case "Heading 03":
      value = 3;
      break;
    default:
      value = false;
      break;
    }
    this.editor.formatText(selection.index, selection.length, {header: value}, "api");
    // this.editor.format("header", value);
    this.setState({header: h});
  }
```

I need to change the selected text into headeing1/2/3, depending on what the user selects. For that I'm getting the range of the selected text and trying to use formatText method of quill. But it is not working nor its giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem as you. I spent hours to find the solution...
If you want to format 'header', you must add 'header' into formats array firstly.
The below is pseudocode：

```
this.editor.formatText(selection.index, selection.length, {header: 1});
const formats = ['header', 'bold']
<ReactQuill
   formats={formats}
   ...
/>
```

Hope it helps you